# Extracting data (to CSV) from Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, node.js

Currently, I am making a website that read a CSV files and put it in the HTML. Now, I want to extract an array from my javascript HTML, to create a csv file. Is it possible to do that? If possible, please guide me.

Comment: I tried using ActivexObject, but it cannot work

Comment: Could you please post your code or what you have tried?

Comment: This is a comment because I do not know if you have access to a backend of not. If you are running node, look at this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Comment: I am not running any node. It just usual HTML CSS Javascript. I manage to read csv, but I cannot save an array to csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Blob and save it using the download attribute in links

```js
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    a.hidden = true
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'octet/stream'})
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
        a.href = url
        a.download = fileName
        a.click()
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
    }
}())

// I leave it up to you to create the data
// necessary for creating the csv data.
// 
// data can also be array buffers blob or
// other stuff the blob constructor can take.
var data = 'abc,123' 
var fileName = "my-download.csv"

saveData(data, fileName)
```

Comment: HI @Endless, It works when I press Run code snippet, but after I copy it to my script, It did not work. It just not download it at all
Please guide me this solution

Comment: I did IT WOHOO!!!!, Thank you Endless ! Really appreciated your help bro

Answer (score 0):

Use the below plugin from the link and export easily.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Exporting-Html-Tables-To-CSV-XLS-XLSX-Text-TableExport/

Comment: You should provide a code snippet and not link to some other site, also what makes you think he use jQuery? He might not even use tabels

Comment: Yeah, I do not use jQuery, Thanks Rajesh Kumaresan but the solution that you gave me is from table to CSV and I prefer from my array to CSV files, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the below code for exporting HTML table data to Excel with javascript.

Sample Html Code:-

```
<button id="btnExport">Export to xls</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="table_wrapper">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#222" id="list">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>user_id</th>
          <th>firstname</th>
          <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>User1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>User 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Test</td>
          <td>User 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript code:-

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('table_wrapper');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = 'exported_table_data + '.xls';
    a.click();
  });
```

I think it will help u..

Comment: Thanks! , let me try this method first